# extract value using regular expression in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am storing values in database like this

```
www/content/lessons/40/Digital Library/document1.doc
```

I need to extract the file **document.doc**.

How to retrieve this value from mysql using regular expression.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you not need to use regexp (low performence)
use substring_index instead

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX('bbb/bbbbbb/bbbbbbbbb/bbbb', '/', -1);
```

link :

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not provide regex based extraction from strings, but you can extend mysql to do this:

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

It's not a good solution for a lot of people though.  eg you couldn't use it in a shared hosting environment.